# Redirect loop problem, elements + elementor

Tags: wordpress, loops, web, redirect, host

I was developing a website in wordpress with usage of plugins Envato Elements and Elementor, and after I was almost done I wanted to set my new homepage and I accidentally created Redirect loop and now I can't access wp-admin, its hosted on google cloud which don't offer technical support for free trial. I tried to disable plugins by changing name of plugins folder to plugins_disable but I have problems using mv command which is not only renaming but moving files... I maybe need to change that in database but I have no idea how, can you please check that out and point me in good direction?

Link to website: http://34.118.78.190/
Link to home redirect loop: http://34.118.78.190/?elementor_library=home-2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Man I think I put enough information about this redirect loop problem, if you need any additional information please specify what kind of